# Local and Global Symmetries

Tags: terminology, symmetry, gauge-theory, field-theory, gauge-invariance

Could somebody point me in the direction of a mathematically rigorous definition [local symmetries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_symmetry) and [global symmetries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_symmetry) for a given (classical) field theory?

Heuristically I know that global symmetries "act the same at every point in spacetime", whereas local symmetries "depend on the point in spacetime at which they act".

But this seems somehow unsatisfying. After all, Lorentz symmetry for a scalar field $\psi(x)\rightarrow \psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ is conventionally called a global symmetry, but also clearly $\Lambda^{-1}x$ depends on $x$. So naively applying the above aphorisms doesn't work!

I've pieced together the following definition from various sources, including [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0009058). I think it's wrong though, and I'm confusing different principles that aren't yet clear in my head. Do people agree?

A **global symmetry** is a symmetry arising from the action of a finite dimensional Lie group (e.g. Lorentz group, $U(1)$)

A **local symmetry** is a symmetry arising from the action of an infinite dimensional Lie group.

If that's right, how do you view the local symmetry of electromagnetism $A^{\mu}\rightarrow A^{\mu}+\partial^{\mu}\lambda$ as the action of a Lie group?

Comment: Your example (v3) is called global symmetry because $\Lambda$ does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your proposed definitions are not quite correct.  I'll sketch correct definitions, but I won't actually give them because I don't know how you choose to define classical field theory.

A group of local symmetries is a group of symmetry transformations where you get to change the system differently at different places in space/time.

A symmetry is global (in the context of field theory) if it acts in the same way at every point.

Local symmetries are necessarily infinite-dimensional, unless the spacetime manifold consists of finitely many points (which happens in lattice gauge theory).  Global symmetries are usually finite-dimensional.  Field theories which have infinitely many global symmetries are either very interesting, or not very interesting, depending on who you hang out with.

Gauge symmetries are usually local symmetries.  They don't have to be.  You can gauge a global $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$, if you're in the mood to.  But the most useful gauge symmetries are the ones which allow us to describe the physics of electromagnetism and the nuclear forces in terms of variables with local interactions.  Our description of gravity in terms of a metric tensor also involves gauge symmetries.  This is perhaps more puzzling than useful.

Let $\Sigma$ be the spacetime, probably $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$.  The local symmetry of the $1$-form description of electromagnetism is an action of the group $\mathcal{G} = \{ \lambda: \Sigma \to U(1) \}$ on the field space $\mathcal{F} \simeq \Omega^1(\Sigma)$, in which $\lambda$ sends the 1-form $A$ to the $1$-form $\lambda \dot{} A$ given at each $x$ in $\Sigma$ by
$$
(\lambda \dot{} A)_\mu(x) = A_\mu(x) + \lambda^{-1}\partial_\mu \lambda(x).
$$
The group of gauge transformations is the subgroup $\mathcal{G}_0$ of functions which become the identity at infinity.  We apparently can't measure anything about electromagnetic phenomena which depends on $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$, except through the quotient $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{G}_0$.

Comment: Can you point to an example of a gauged global $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ please? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Great answer. I might add that many physicist use a slightly different definition of "gauge group". Instead of considering the space of maps (which is infinite-dimensional) $M\rightarrow G$ as the gauge group, people usually call $G$ the gauge group (which is usually finite-dimensional).

Comment: @MichaelBrown:  A silly example:  Suppose you want to describe the classical mechanics of a particle on $\mathbb{R}P^2$.  Maps to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ are probably most easily thought of as maps to $S^2$, modulo the obvious global action of $Z/2$.

Comment: @Heidar:  Yes.  I avoided using this term.  But I agree:  It's a good convention to say gauge group for target space, and group of local transformations for maps to this space, and group of gauge transformations for the subgroup of the local transformations which are actually gauge transformations (the ones which vanish at infinity).

Comment: ...and then I edited the answer to include the terms...

Comment: Marvellous answer - that's clarified everything a lot, many thanks!

Comment: @user1504: Just one question, why does your $\lambda$ have to map into $U(1)$? Would a more general $\lambda$ with target space $\mathbb{C}$ not work, for some reason?

Comment: @EdwardHughes:  Note that I made a typo in that last equation.  Forgot a factor of $\lambda^{-1}$, which makes the second term equal to $\partial_\mu \operatorname{ln}(\lambda(x))$.  $\lambda$ shouldn't take values in $\mathbb{C}^\times$, because then we'd be adding complex-valued forms to real forms, after already deciding to represent the gauge field by real-valued 1-forms.

Comment: Ah right that makes more sense now! Cheers!

Comment: @user1504: You say you could gauge a global ℤ/ℤ. I am confused by the use of "gauge" as a verb in this context. What do you do if you gauge something?

Comment: @Friedrich:   For brevity, I'll explain in classical physics.  If you have a group $G$ acting on the space $H$ of histories, to 'gauge' $G$ means to consider a different classical system whose space of histories is the quotient $H/G$.

Comment: @user1504 Could you kindly explain in mode detail why you identify the gauge group not with $\mathcal{G}$ but with $\mathcal{G}_0\,$? And why do we single out the transformations which become the identity at infinity? Books on electrodynamics say that *any* gauge transformation from the group $\mathcal{G}$ leaves the actual physics unchanged (like the measurable fields $B_{\mu}$ and $E_\mu$). I now see that the standard texts for physicists are missing something big.

Comment: @Michael_1812  The constant functions are a copy of G.   G is the global symmetry group whose associated conserved quantity is the charge.  It actually acts on states, so can't be a gauge transformation.  We restrict to functions $\mathcal{G}_c$ which are constant at infinity to avoid nasty analysis issues.  Then $\mathcal{G}_c \simeq \mathcal{G}_0 \times G$.

Comment: @user1504 I am now even more confused. You said: "If you have a group G acting on the space H of histories, to gauge G means to consider a different classical system whose space of histories is the quotient H/G. " Why *different*? In electrodynamics, what you said means that G is acting on H in such a way that the mathematical form of histories changes, but the physical sector of the theory remains invariant. Stated alternatively, while the histories of $A_\mu$ change under the action of G, the histories of the physical fields $E_\mu$ and $B_\mu$ stay the same. Hence H/G.  Did I get it right?

Comment: @Michael_1812 think the trouble is that I am using $G$ inconsistently, having lost track of the notation in the decade since I wrote this answer.   In my last answer, I was using $G$ to refer to the gauge group.  Perhaps I should have used $U$ or something, as the group is $U(1)$ in electromagnetism.  In the earlier comment, I was using $G$ to refer to the group of gauge transformations, which I've mostly written as $\mathcal{G}$.   And yes, you've basically got it right.

Comment: @user1504 Glad I got it right! Owing to the gauge freedom described by the group G, the space of histories factorises from H to H/G, the latter space describing the physical sector of the theory. Now, what is ${\cal G}_0\,$? (Or shall we now call it $G_0\,$?)

Comment: @Michael_1812  Let's not make the notation any worse.    Good notation would be to write $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{G}$ instead of $H/G$ and reserve $G$ for a Lie group or a finite group.  So $\mathcal{G}_0$ is the group of $U(1)$-valued functions which asymptote to the identity.   That's the group of gauge transformations of electromagnetism.   Then the space of physical histories is $\{A_\mu\} / \mathcal{G}_0$.

Comment: @user1504 Now I see new entities. Is $\cal F$ the space of histories? If $\left\{ A_\mu\right\}$ is the same as $\cal F$, then, to get the physical sector of the theory, we should factorise it over the entire group of gauge transformations. (Do you call it $\cal G\,$?) Why do you factorise it over a subgroup $\cal{G}_0\,$?

Comment: @user1504 Stated alternatively: by taking a mathematical solution $A_\mu$, and applying to it all gauge transformations from a group $\cal G$, we build a whole class of solutions. This class, however, corresponds to the same physical history. So, to single out physical histories, we have to take the set of all mathematical histories and factorise it over $\cal G$. Isn't that right? How do the gauge transformations emerge which asymptote to the identity? What is so special about them?